# Iterated integral change the order and go to polar coordinates

Tags: integration, solution-verification, polar-coordinates, change-of-variable, iterated-integrals

I have an iterated integral with these two homework assignments on it :
(1) change the order of integration
(2) go to polar coordinates and set the limits of integration according to new ones variables.

I think I was able to solve both of these tasks, please tell me if I did it correctly? Thank you very much!

The iterated integral is:

$$\int_{0}^{1}dx\int_{x^3}^{x^2}f(x;y)dy$$

(1) **change the order of integration**

[image: Graphing]

My answer is

$$\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_{\sqrt{y}}^{\sqrt[3]y}f(x;y)dx$$

**Solve:**

Let's find the inverse functions, taking into account the fact that we are in the first quarter of the Cartesian coordinate system
$y = x^2 = > x = \sqrt(y)$, $y = x^3 => x = \sqrt[3]{y}$
on the segment $0 \leq x \leq 1$
$$\sqrt{y} \leq \sqrt[3]{y}$$

(2) **go to polar coordinates and set the limits of integration according to new ones variables**

My answer is

$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}d\phi\int_{\frac{sin(\phi)}{cos^2(\phi)}}^
{\sqrt{\frac{sin(\phi)}{cos^3(\phi)}}}
f(r*cos(\phi); r*sin(\phi))r*dr$$

**Solve:**

Since the outer integral in our case with $d\phi$, then we fix the angle and see how $r$ will change depending on it. We see that r goes from the red graph to the blue one.
Red to polar:
$$y = x^2$$
$$rsin(\phi) = r^2cos^2(\phi)$$
$$r = \frac{sin(\phi)}{cos^2(\phi)}$$
Blue to polar:
$$y = x^3$$
$$rsin(\phi) = r^3*cos^3(\phi)$$
$$r^2 = \frac{sin(\phi)}{cos^3(\phi)}$$
Choosing the positive
$$r = \sqrt{\frac{sin(\phi)}{cos^3(\phi)}}$$
We have found the boundaries and therefore can substitute them into our polar integral:
$$\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}d\phi\int_{\frac{sin(\phi)}{cos^2(\phi)}}^
{\sqrt{\frac{sin(\phi)}{cos^3(\phi)}}}
f(r*cos(\phi); r*sin(\phi))r*dr$$

Comment: The region of integration is given by $$\left\{(x,y): 0 \le x \le 1, x^3 < y < x^2\right\}.$$
This is equivalent to $$\left\{(x,y): 0 \le y \le 1: y^{1/2} < x < y^{1/3} \right\}.$$
So your expression after changing the order of integration is almost correct, but the limits on the $x$-integral should be the other way round. I don't think the polar integral is right.

Comment: @kipf, Thanks! Tell me, please, maybe now the polar integral is correct?

Comment: It is more pedagogical if you gave us your proof that your polar integral is correct. kipf has demonstrated how to do those things in the Cartesian case.

Comment: @KurtG.Added solution

Comment: Looks right. $\phantom{.}$

Comment: It looks right & you can Double Check by (1) Converting the Order back & by (2) Converting Polar to Cartesian back. You will get back the Original. Alternately , you can take some Example $f(x,y)$ & calculate the Integral value via all ways. Exact Same value is the Confirmation.